# Nature of Fourier coefficient of a modular form after applying a certain map (trace operator)

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

Asking this here because of no response at ([MathStackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3542368/nature-of-fourier-coefficient-of-a-modular-form-after-applying-a-certain-map-tr)).

Let $N|M$, and consider the trace operator $Tr^M_N$  defined on $M_k(\Gamma_0(M))$ - vector space of modular forms of weight $k$ for the congruence subgroup $\Gamma_0(M)$, mapping it to $M_k(\Gamma_0(N))$ (level lowering operator). It is defined as $$(Tr_N^M f)(z) = \sum\limits_{\begin{pmatrix} a &b\\c & d \end{pmatrix}\in \Gamma_0(N) \ \backslash \Gamma_0(M)} (cz+d)^{-k}f\left(\frac{az+b}{cz+d}\right),$$ where the sum varies over representatives. Assume $f = \sum_{n\geq1} a_f(n)q^n$ is a cusp form in $M_k(\Gamma_0(M))$, with $rational$ Fourier coefficients. Is it easy to derive the nature of coefficients of $(Tr_N^M f)(z)$ - i.e., whether they are still rational or not ? Finding out the explicit Fourier expansion is one way, but it seems bit lenghty(and tediuos), hence asking for help.

I think [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/231751/computing-coefficients-for-the-slash-operator-of-a-modular-form?rq=1) might be a kinda-related/helpful question in this regard, but I am unsure of it.

Comment: Yes, it stays rational. There is a very precise relation on how conjugating coefficients by an element in Aut$(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Q})$ interact with a slash operator, e.g. Thm 3.3 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.00391.pdf. Then it becomes just the matter of whether you can choose representatives of $\Gamma_{0}(N)/\Gamma_{0}(M)$ accordingly.

Comment: @GTA Thanks for pointing out the reference. I have not come across this one previously. I will look into this and work out the details(and hopefully write an answer ).

Comment: The conceptual reason is that the trace map has a purely algebraic definition: in weight 2, this is just the push-forward of differential forms $\Omega^1(X_0(N)) \to \Omega^1(X_0(M))$. Since the map $X_0(N) \to X_0(M)$ is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, the trace map preserves rationality. (This argument works in weight 2 but can be extended to higher weight.)

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault Thanks for an alternate way to see it(I am not much comfortable looking at the trace map in that way, but I will try to see how it can be done in higher weight). Will this work for weight $k+1/2$ modular forms?

Comment: I'm not sure about half-integral weight (the metaplectic cover of SL_2 does not give rise to an algebraic curve, if I recall correctly). One trick would be to multiply by $\theta$ and prove something like $\mathrm{Tr}(f \theta) = \mathrm{Tr}(f) \theta$.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault I will try to work it out.